# Closing over a variable in Python

Tags: python

In Scheme I can say

```
(define f
  (let ((a (... some long computation ...)))
    (lambda (args)
      (...some expression involving a ...))))
```

Then the long computation that computes `a` will be performed only once, and `a` will be available inside the lambda. I can even `set!` `a` to some different value.

How do I accomplish the same thing in Python?

I've looked at lots of Google references to 'Python closures' and all of them refer to multiple local procedures inside an outer procedure, which is not what I want.

EDIT: I want to write a function that determines if a number is a perfect square. This code works using quadratic residues to various bases, and is quite fast, calling the expensive square root function only 6 times out of 715 (less than 1%) on average:

```
def iroot(k, n): # newton
  u, s = n, n+1
  while u < s:
    s = u
    t=(k-1)*s+n//pow(s,k-1)
    u = t // k
  return s

from sets import Set

q64 = Set()
for k in xrange(0,64):
  q64.add(pow(k,2,64))

q63 = Set()
for k in xrange(0,63):
  q63.add(pow(k,2,63))

q65 = Set()
for k in xrange(0,65):
  q65.add(pow(k,2,65))

q11 = Set()
for k in xrange(0,11):
  q11.add(pow(k,2,11))

def isSquare(n):
  if n % 64 not in q64:
    return False
  r = n % 45045
  if r % 63 not in q63:
    return False
  if r % 65 not in q65:
    return False
  if r % 11 not in q11:
    return False
  s = iroot(2, n)
  return s * s == n
```

I want to hide the computations of q64, q63, q65 and q11 inside the isSquare function, so no other code can modify them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

A typical Python closure combined with the fact that functions are first-class citizens in this language looks almost like what you're requesting:

```py
def f(arg1, arg2):
  a = tremendously_long_computation()

  def closure():
    return a + arg1 + arg2  # sorry, lack of imaginantion

  return closure
```

Here, a call to `f(arg1, arg2)` will return a function which closes over `a` and has it already computed. The only difference is that `a` is read-only since a closure is constructed using static program's text (this is, however, may be evaded with ugly solutions, which involve using mutable containers).

As for Python 3, the latter seems to be achievable with `nonlocal` keyword.

**EDIT:** for your purpose, a caching [decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator) seems the best choice:

```py
import functools


def memoize(f):
  if not hasattr(f, "cache"):
    f.cache = {}

  @functools.wraps(f)
  def caching_function(*args, **kwargs):
    key = (args, tuple(sorted(kwargs.items())))
    if key not in f.cache:
      result = f(*args, **kwargs)
      f.cache[key] = result
    return f.cache[key]

  return caching_function


@memoize
def q(base):
  return set(pow(k, 2, base) for k in xrange(0, base))


def test(n, base):
  return n % base in q(base)


def is_square(n):
  if not test(n, 64):
    return False

  r = n % 45045
  if not all((test(r, 63), test(r, 65), test(r, 11))):
    return False

  s = iroot(2, n)
  return s * s == n
```

This way, `q(base)` is calculated exactly once for every `base`. Oh, and you could have made `iroot` and `is_square` cache-able as well!

**Of course,** my implementation of a caching decorator is error-prone and doesn't look after memory it consumes -- better make use of [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) (at least in Python 3), but it gives a good understanding of what goes on.

Comment: But I don't want a function `f`. Who would call it?

Comment: You could move your computations into isSquare and use a cache.